# PHP : How to print Php syntax in html

Tags: php

I am wondering is it possible to print php syntax on html page.For example below is the php syntax i want to echo on html page via php.

```
Please <?php echo $random[array_rand($random)]; ?> the [url=http://feeds.feedburner.com]hello[/url].<br>
Also [url=http://feeds.feedburner.com]<?php echo $random[array_rand($random)]; ?>[/url].
<br>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$str='Please <?php echo $random[array_rand($random)]; ?> the [url=http://feeds.feedburner.com]hello[/url].<br>
Also [url=http://feeds.feedburner.com]<?php echo $random[array_rand($random)]; ?>[/url].
<br>';

echo highlight_string($str);

?>
```

Output:

[image: highlights]

Comment: I'd been using `exec( "php -s ..." )` all this time :S

Comment: Interesting function... Is it possible to replace `style="..."` with `class="..."` and manually add styles for classes?

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.syntax-highlighting). I haven't seen anything that can change `style` directly, and I wouldn't want to parse html either.

Answer (score 1):

use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for print Php syntax in html

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<?php echo "Hello, World!"; ?>');
```

**Output**

```
<?php echo "Hello, World!"; ?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/J2X0yn)

Comment: can i get online generator for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [highlight_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) to highlight syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use character references for characters with special meaning.

`&lt;php echo` etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it from a file, use

```
highligh_code($filename);
```